# Is a block changed programmaticaly with hook_block_view_alter cached?

Tags: caching

I have a lateral section which will be different for every page in my site, but the content is practically unaltered for every single page.

I had the intention of using hook_block_view_alter. I would create an empty block in the region, and would fill the content dinamically with PHP in a hook in a custom module.

Will the content be cached or should I better create different blocks for every single page and change the content only if the content changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hook_block_view_alter() isn't going to affect the cache settings for the block automatically, though you can find a way if you really want to as Molot points out below; typically you use hook_block_info_alter() to change the cache settings for a block:

```
function mymodule_block_info_alter(&$blocks, $theme, $code_blocks) {
  $blocks['block']['my_block_id']['cache'] = DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE;
}
```

Here, DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE will cache your block for each page, which could be quite a bit better than not caching at all and creating the content dynamically for each page. If you need dynamic content every time, choose DRUPAL_NO_CACHE. Clear the block cache to make Drupal aware of your new settings.

But! If you are prepared to have a custom module to run alter hooks, consider writing a block from scratch. If you are going to have a custom block, I feel that it helps if it is impossible to accidentally delete in the Drupal UI.

To implement a basic block you need [hook_block_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7).

hook_block_info is where you tell Drupal that the block exists and how to cache it:

```
function mymodule_block_info() {
  $blocks['myblock'] = array(
    'info' => t('My Awesome Block'),
    'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE,
  );
  return $blocks;
}
```

Next, hook_block_view does the work of generating the content. I find that assigning the content to a callback makes my code easier to read, but do what works for you. Using switch() makes it easy to add more blocks to your module later on.

```
function mymodule_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();

  switch ($delta) {

    case 'myblock':
      $block['subject'] = t('My awesome block');
      $block['content'] = mymodule_some_function_to_build_the_block_content();
      break;

  }

  return $block;
}
```

Comment: It is a really detailed reply. Thank you very much. I was able to create a new block and assign it to a region with the IU. However, I found 2 problems: 1st was that the cache was not used, because I had the restriction: "Block caching is inactive because you have enabled modules defining content access restrictions." I was able to override this by configuring settings.php uncommenting the line: $conf['block_cache_bypass_node_grants'] = TRUE; The second problem I am investigating, is that the block is rendered in memory even if the region is not called. Maybe with a rule in template.tpl.php.

Comment: Do you mean that you are rendering regions conditionally within your theme templates? I think a more typical approach is to always render the regions but to include the blocks conditionally, e.g. with the Context module or the basic block configuration in core.

Comment: Yes, I make as you say, I had deleted the block programmaticaly (erasing the code in hook_block_info) and I forgot to select the pages where to display the block. I avoid logic in the template as much as I can, only for doing 'theme_hook_suggestion' and views_embed_view (I don't want to use Context or Panels modules).

Comment: Actually I believe you *can* do things that break cache in `hook_block_view_alter()`. The point is, it **shouldn't** be done that way, not that it can't. +1 from me, I just wanted to clarify it a bit, that's all.

Comment: @Cesar, I don't understand the situation where a "region is not called". When does this happen?

Comment: @calebtr, sorry for the comment, it was just that I had put a list of nodes where to show the block, but after the tests, the block had been programmaticaly deleted. When I created it again I forgot to assign the displayable nodes again and thought that the hook was called in every page -- indeed that was the case, until I restricted the display to a few selected nodes again. Everything working as expected, thanks.